# Web scrape data in performance gauge

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I'm trying to scrape data in a widget using python and the requests-html library.

The the value I want is in a gauge with an arrow pointing to five possible results.
Each label on the gauge is the same on all pages of the website. The problem I face is I cannot use a css selector on the gauge labels to extract the text, I need to extract the value of the arrow itself as it will be pointing to a label. The arrow doesn't have a text attribute so if I use a css selector I get none as a response.

Each arrow has a unique class name.

```
<div class="arrow-F-uE7IX8 arrowToStrongBuy-1ydGKDOo arrowStrongBuyShudder-3xsGK8k5">
https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-MDB/
StrongBuy:

<div class="arrow-F-uE7IX8 arrowToBuy-1R7d8UMJ arrowBuyShudder-3GMCnG5u">
https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NYSE-XOM/
Buy:

<div class="arrow-F-uE7IX8 arrowToStrongSell-3UWimXJs arrowStrongSellShudder-2UJhm0_C">
https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-IDEX/ 
StrongSell:
```

What can I do to ensure I get the correct value? I'm not sure how I can check if the selector contains the arrowTo{**foo**} and store as variable.

```
import pyppdf.patch_pyppeteer
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
asession = AsyncHTMLSession()


async def get_page():
    code = 'NASDAQ-MDB'
    r = await asession.get(f'https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/{code}/')
    await r.html.arender(wait=3)
    return r

results = asession.run(get_page)
for result in results:

    arrow_class_placeholder = "//div[contains(@class,'arrow-F-uE7IX8 arrowToStrongBuy-1ydGKDOo')]//div[1]"
    arrow_class_name = result.html.xpath(arrow_class_placeholder,first=True)

    if arrow_class_name == "//div[contains(@class,'arrow-F-uE7IX8 arrowToStrongBuy-1ydGKDOo')]//div[1]":
        print('StrongBuy')
    else:
        print('not strong buy')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BeautifulSoup4 (bs4)](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), which is a a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files, with a combination of [Regular Expressions (RegEx)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). In this case I used the python [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library for the RegEx purposes.

Something like this is what you want ([source](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)):

[image]

In the example above `soup.find_all(class_=re.compile("itle"))` returns all instances where the word "itle" is found in the class tag, such as `class = "title"` from the html document shown below.

[image]

For your RegEx it would look something like `"arrowTo*"` or even just `"arrowTo"`.  `soup.find_all(class_=re.compile("arrowTo"))`.

Your final code should look something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#i think result was your html document from requests library
#the first parameter is your html document variable
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser') 
myArrowToList = soup.find_all(class_=re.compile("arrowTo"))
```

If you wanted `"arrowToStrongBuy"` just use that in the regex input to the `find_all` function.

```
soup.find_all(class_=re.compile("arrowToStrongBuy"))
```

Comment: When I try your solution I get an error ```encoding
    declared_encoding_match = xml_re.search(markup, endpos=xml_endpos)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object```
Do you know how to fix?

Comment: check the encoding of the input document?

Comment: I've just realised that the xpath's aren't being found in the response Results so  requests-html isn't rendering properly.